# Audio out on Linux to play on Windows

Tags: windows-7, linux, audio-streaming

I have a Windows 7 computer I use for gaming, and a Linux machine I use for everything else. Everything else is relatively easy to switch (one plug for keyboard/mouse, and the linux box uses VGA while the Windows 7 is using DVI so it's just an input toggle ), so a KVM seems over kill, and most are pricey and do not receive great reviews. The audio jacks are hard to reach and thus hard to switch. These computers sit close to each other, one is just buried in a desk.

What I'd like to do is have Windows 7 be able to play any sound output on the Linux machine. This would mostly be for video's on the internet (youtube) and video's played via Smplayer (tv shows).

Other suggestions are welcome it may be there is something I haven't considered.

Answer (score 0):

**Keyboard and Mouse:**

If you want to remove the step where you change your keyboard and mouse, check out Synergy (Free) http://synergy-foss.org/

**Audio:**

**Method 1:**

Buy an audio switch. Such as http://www.ebay.com/itm/2-PORT-3-5mm-STEREO-Manual-Sharing-Switch-BOX-Audio-Speaker-selector-way-2-1-/121037251872?pt=US_Audio_Cables_Adapters&hash=item1c2e61e520

**Method 2:**

Does your Windows 7 computer have a microphone/input port and a sound card that supports pass-through?  If so, you could plug in your Linux audio output into the Windows 7 audio input and enable the pass through option on the sound card (Refer to your audio card manufacturer to see if this feature is supported in your model).  Otherwise, you can try using third party microphone pass-through software (Note that software pass through can have latency problems).

**Method 3**

(NOT RECOMMENDED) Go cheap and easy, just use an audio splitter. Such as: http://www.ebay.com/itm/3-5mm-Stereo-Audio-Y-Splitter-1-Female-to-2-Male-ADAPTER-ADAPTOR-Cable-KABLE-NEW-/271054286433?pt=US_Audio_Video_Transmitters&hash=item3f1c182e61
DISCLAIMER, this **may** damage the audio cards!

**Discalimer:**

I have not tried any of the specific products listed other than synergy and do not know how well they will work. Do your research before you buy.

Comment: synergy would only work well if I had multiple monitors, AFAIK it is designed to be used with multiple systems with multiple monitors, not multiple systems 1 monitor.